# Set a redirect into a custom Authentication Failure Handler with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

Which is the properly way to set a redirect into a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler in Spring?

Is it possible to *call* a controller?

The code is as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);

        if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(
                CustomUsernameNotFoundException.class)) {

            // TODO Set the redirect

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question... "*redirecting into custom authentication failure handler"* does not make much sense. What is your usecase? `AuthenticationFailureHandler` is there to handle failed authentications. Now the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` is implementation of this handler which does HTTP redirection. So what special case you need to implement?

Comment: To be clear. The system had to perform a third-part authentication. There are two main cases: 1) the user exists both in my system and in the third-part IdP 2) the user exists in the third-part IdP but there isn't yet in my system. In the second case, I'd like to perform a redirect to a sign-up page by storing the nameID retrieved from the third-part IdP in order to use this data during the accounting-process.

Comment: How are you integrating with the 3rd party IdP? Do you have your own `AuthenticationProvider`? Or in other words - which part of your code / component detects that user is not in your database?

Comment: Btw. your code in the question seems fine... is there some specific issue with it? You can check `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` to see how to implement the redirect itself. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler.java (or maybe use that class instead of implementing your own).

Comment: I'm using Spring SAML, this I'm using a SAML-based authentication provider. All works fine, now I've just to set the redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `super.onAuthenticationFailure` which will peform a redirect to the configured URL. The response is thus already committed and you cannot decide to redirect somewhere else.

You can configure `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` to redirect to one URL and only call the super method if you aren't going to do a redirect yourself.

Alternatively, implement `AuthenticationFailureHandler` directly and implement all the logic you want in the failure method - once things get beyond a certain level of complexity I prefer to avoid inheritance altogether:

```
if (oneCondition) {
    // redirect to IdP

} else {
    // redirect to registration page
}
```

Comment: Then you need to debug your app and find out why the response is committed.

Comment: Implementing directly the AuthenticationFaliureHandler, it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try soemthing like this

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        saveException(request, exception);
        //do your things
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/page/login?error=Retry");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a specific URL.

```
response.sendRedirect("/redirect");
```

Comment: The app returns this error: "HTTP Status 500 - Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed"

Comment: Can you please try this:                                                     public class LoginFailure extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

 @Override
 public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.sendRedirect("/redirect");
 }

}

Comment: I've the exception as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a controller., a code snippet from you would help, but am getting this from the example that is discussed here.,

[Spring Security Tutorial](https://github.com/krams915/spring-security-tutorial)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/failure")
public String loginFailure() {
    String message = "Login Failure!";
    return "redirect:/login?message="+message;
}
```

make sure you understand how the redirect works by looking at the mapping for login in the xml

[Spring Mapping.xml](https://github.com/krams915/spring-security-tutorial/blob/master/spring-security-tutorial/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml)

Comment: I've to perform a redirect just for my own custom exception. I'd like to call a controller and set a certain attribute (I could pass it as http param).